# Adding Ammo Count to Game.

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

I've been attempting to add this functionality for quite some time now. However, it seems that I’m overlooking something.

So I want to add an ammo count, a single ammo count similar to that of Quake or Doom. With ammo pickups distributed throughout the map. The gun can fire up to 10 times then stops, but when I attempt to reload by overlapping with an ammo pickup the the static mesh does not respond. The static mash parent is a blueprint (actor) its parent class is ammocrate.cpp (below) which is also a actor. This is what I’ve done so far.

**AmmoCrate.cpp**

```
 AAmmoCrate::AAmmoCrate()
    {
        PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

        Count = 10;
        SphereRadius = 100.0f;

        TouchSphere = CreateDefaultSubobject<USphereComponent>(TEXT("TouchSphereComponent"));
        TouchSphere->InitSphereRadius(SphereRadius);
        TouchSphere->SetCollisionProfileName("Trigger");
        RootComponent = TouchSphere;

        StaticMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("StaticMeshComponent"));
        StaticMesh->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);

        TouchSphere->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AAmmoCrate::OnOverlapBegin);
    }

    void AAmmoCrate::OnOverlapBegin(class UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComp, class AActor* OtherActor, class UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
    {
        AFirstPersonCharacter *FPCharacter = Cast<AFirstPersonCharacter>(OtherActor);
        AMannequin* TPCharacter = Cast<AMannequin>(OtherActor);
        AGun *Gun = Cast<AGun>(OtherActor);

if (TPCharacter)
{
    Gun->AmmoPool = Gun->AmmoPool + Count;

    this->Destroy();
}
```

Afterwards I created a OnReload() function similar to the OnFire() function, where I call it from the First Person Character.

**FirstPersonCharacter.cpp**

```
void AFirstPersonCharacter::OnReload()
{
    Gun->OnReload();
}
```

I's set up a UE_LOG call on the OnReload function it does not even log out that the ammo crate has been overlapped with, what am I missing here ?

Comment: Is your overlap volume bigger than your mesh?

Answer (score 0):

Is GenerateOverlapEvents checked to true in collision settings of both FPS character capsule and ammo crate collider?
Are both colliders in proper channels that can generate the overlapping events?